# Google Chrome Javascript Text Set In Input Element Disappears On Next Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to put text in in an HTML input element.  I extract the input elements as shown in the code using jquery.  That works fine.  I then change the value attribute which appears in the text box temporarily and in the properties list.  But then the text disappears on the next event that triggers.  I looked at the properties of the input element and there are two attributes that seem to matter.  "value" and "_value".  If both are set in the attribute list the text in the box stays put.  I have tried various methods to trigger the change event.  Thinking that would set the _value attribute but it does not.  I have tried changing the _value by setting the attribute.  It only adds it to the input element but does not set the value in the property list.   I have also tried copy/paste the text  which works when I manually do it.  I need help in understanding what is going on and how to  input the text so it doe not disappear on me.

```
~~~~~~Javascript Snippet

    var inputs = $("section.listing-editor__section input");
    console.log(inputs.length);
  inputs.each((l) => console.log(inputs[l]));
  inputs[1].focus();
  inputs[1].select();
  inputs[1].value = "test21";  //TITLE
    inputs[1].setAttribute("_value" , "test21");

  ~~~~~~~~~~~~



~~~~~~~HTML
<input type="text" placeholder="What is Item Title? (required)" maxlength="50" data-vv-name="title" class="form__text p--3" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but I think that setting the value of an input element and setting the value of the "value" attribute of an input element are 2 different things.

Comment: Setting the value seems to put the text in the box and sets the value attribute. I think I need to trigger an event to make it somewhat permanent.  I read that triggering the change event or changing focus should end the change.

Comment: Figured out how to do document.execCommand('copy') and execCommand('paste') to get it to work.  Have to set clipboardRead and clipboardWrite permissions in the manifest.json file